# Problema com char * e fgets()

Tags: c++, char

Tenho um `struct` com um campo do tipo vetor de `char` e tenho um arquivo `.txt` com varias linhas nesse formato com nome de músicas.

> texto1
>  texto2
>  texto3
>  texto4

Preciso ler o arquivo inteiro linha por linha e armazenar cada linha em uma posição do vetor de `struct`. Fiz esse código aqui, porém ele armazena o ultima linha em todos as posições do vetor desse `struct`.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    struct musica2{
       char *musica;
    };

    int main(){
       FILE *arquivo;
       musica2 *z = new musica2[12];
       char a[255];
       arquivo = fopen("teste.dat", "r");
       int i=0;
       if(arquivo == NULL)
           cout << "Erro ao abrir arquivo." << endl;
       else{
        while(!feof(arquivo)){
        z[i].musica = fgets(a,255,arquivo);
        i++;
       }
      }
    cout << z[3].musica;
    fclose(arquivo);
    return 0;
    }
```

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
z[i].musica = fgets(a,255,arquivo);
```

Aqui você está fazendo duas coisas:

1. Sobreescrevendo o `a` a cada linha lida
2. Apontando todos os vetores para `a`

Desta forma, ao iterar os vetores, terá o mesmo retorno para todos.

A solução seria copiar o valor de `a` para o vetor, ou eliminar o `a` completamente apontar diretamente o ítem do vetor no `fgets`, como neste exemplo:

```
struct musica2{
   char musica[255];
};

...

fgets( z[i].musica, 255, arquivo);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9EliT3)**.

> Me atentei apenas ao problema principal. Depois você precisa colocar as devidas proteções para checar o retorno do fgets, e garantir que a string esteja adequadamente formatada.